# How to import Swift protocol in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c

In my swift class I have the next protocol:

```
@objc
public protocol MyDelegate: AnyObject { ... }
```

And I need to access that protocol from the **header** file, not `.m` file.
How can I do this?

I found few cases in SO and I tried them as

```
#import <ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h>
```

and

`@import MySwiftClass;`

but I still cannot use that protocol in my `.h` file in Obj-C.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refering to a Swift class or protocol from a generated header in a `.h` file would create a cyclical reference, therefore it is not possible. Apple suggest using a forward declaration and doing actual import in a `.m` file.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c)

> When declarations in an Objective-C header file refer to a Swift class or protocol that comes from the same target, importing the generated header creates a cyclical reference. To avoid this, use a forward declaration of the Swift class or protocol to reference it in an Objective-C interface.

In other words, what you want is (at least currently) not possible.

Comment: It is possible, you just need to forward declare the protocol in the `.h` file, using `@protocol MyDelegate`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yep, agree, it is possible. But cyclical reference is avoided by forward declarations. Just as you could do with `@class`. And the swift protocol needs to be NSObject depended. Which is with AnyObject not the case as far i remember. You then still use `#import <ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h>` but into the `.m` file

Comment: @DávidPásztor Can confirm you're correct! Just use `@protocol MyDelegate;` to foward declare. Remember the `;`